# How to invoke a C++ function after main() finishes

Tags: c++, function

I am developing a C++ tool that should run transparent to main program. That is: if user simply links the tool to his program the tool will be activated. For that I need to invoke two functions, function `a()`, before `main()` gets control and function `b()` after `main()` finishes.

I can easily do the first by declaring a global variable in my program and have it initialize by return code of `a()`. i.e

```
int v = a() ;
```

but I cannot find a way to call `b()` after `main()` finishes?

Does any one can think of a way to do this?

The tool runs on windows, but I'd rather not use any OS specific calls.

Thank you, George

Comment: you can create an object in main in call function `b` in its destructor

Comment: Isn't [`atexit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) for you?

Comment: Make your global variable class type and put the code in its destructor

Comment: Do you need `b` to be called only if `main` returns, or do you also need it if the program `exit`s?

Answer (score 9):

Use RAII, with a and b called in constructor/destructor.

```
class MyObj {
MyObj()
  {
   a();
  };
~MyObj()
  {
    b();
  };
};
```

Then just have an instance of MyObj outside the scope of main()

```
MyObj obj;

main()
{
  ...
}
```

Some things to note.

- This is bog-standard C++ and will work on any platform
- You can use this without changing ANY existing source code, simply by having your instance of MyObj in a separate compilation unit.
- While it will run before and after main(), any other objects constructed outside main will also run at this time. And you have little control of the order
  of your object's construction/destruction, among those others.

Comment: You could have the instance as a static member of `MyObj` and make everything in the class private, if it's important that each function only gets called once.

Comment: @Biffen Yes. That could make sense. I only explicitly put the object before `main()` to keep the example simple and obvious.

Comment: Thank you!! This is the simplest solution to my problem.. Why I did not think of the destructor myself.....

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION IN C:**

have a look at atexit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void bye(void)
{
    printf("That was all, folks\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    long a;
    int i;
    a = sysconf(_SC_ATEXIT_MAX);
    printf("ATEXIT_MAX = %ld\n", a);
    i = atexit(bye);
    if (i != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot set exit function\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit

this still implies however that you have access to your main and you can add the atexit call. If you have no access to the main and you cannot add this function call I do not think there is any option.

**EDIT:**

**SOLUTION IN C++:**

as sudgested there is a c++ equivalent from std. I simply paste in here an example which i copied from the link available just below the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void atexit_handler_1() 
{
    std::cout << "at exit #1\n";
}

void atexit_handler_2() 
{
    std::cout << "at exit #2\n";
}

int main() 
{
    const int result_1 = std::atexit(atexit_handler_1);
    const int result_2 = std::atexit(atexit_handler_2);

    if ((result_1 != 0) or (result_2 != 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Registration failed\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "returning from main\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit

Comment: As OP mentions the tool runs on Windows, a link to the Windows version of `atexit` may be appropriate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze57ck3.aspx

Comment: The question is tagged C++ but this answer is in C. Not that there would be a huge difference.

Comment: @computerfreaker Or [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).

Comment: CppReference isn't actually the official documentation; the official documentation is ISO standard 14882.

Comment: @Biffen: the C++ example was prefaced with " I simply paste in here the example from the official documentation[sic]". And no, I cannot provide a link to the ISO 14882 document. It's copyrighted and not (legally) available online.

Comment: Sorry for the |"official" i will get read of this word. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to stick with a single compiler and non-standard C/C++, then GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` might be of use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((constructor)) ctor()
{
    printf("Before main()\n");
}

void __attribute__((destructor)) dtor()
{
    printf("After main()\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("main()\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Before main()
main()
After main()
```

Comment: The question is flagged as C++, why would you resort to non-standard and non-portable solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't any global variable constructed before `main` and destructed afterward? I made a test `struct` whose constructor is called before `main` and the destructor afterward.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    Test()  { std::cout << "Before main..." << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "After main..."  << std::endl; }
};

Test test;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Returning now..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the destructor, you can use `atexit()` in a similar manner - in C++, you do not need to have access to `main()` to register `atexit` there. You can do that as well it in your `a()` - for example:

```
void b(void) {
    std::cout << "Exiting.\n";
}

int a(void) {
    std::cout << "Starting.\n";
    atexit(b);
    return 0;
}

// global in your module
int i = a();
```

That being said, I'd also prefer the global C++ class object, which will call the `b()` stuff in its destructor.